# Have two spans line up next to a single span?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the following result, but cannot get the css correct - I keep getting either a span on a new line, or all of the span's inline.

[image: Desired result]

I've tried messing with display, clear, float, etc. and just can't seem to get this to line up?

I can use `table` to do this, and it works fine...but think there must be a css way to acheive the same?

```
<div>
    <span class="button">
        <button type="button">
            CLICK!</button>
    </span>
    <span class="field">
        <span>
            Field 1
        </span>
        <span>
            Field 2
        </span>
    </span>
</div>


.button
{
    margin: 1em 10px 0px 0px;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

.field
{
    margin: 0.5em 0px 0px;
    color: #002c5a;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything??

Comment: Can we see your css? Perhaps a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new css: **Change** `display:inline-block` to `float:left;` in both classes (button & field) and **add** `display:block;` to `.field span {}`.

```
.button
{
    margin: 1em 10px 0px 0px;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: right;
    float:left;
}

.field
{
    float:left;
    margin: 0.5em 0px 0px;
    color: #002c5a;
}
.field span { display:block;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4AwY2/)**

***Demo 2 is with more css that looks like you sample!***

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/4AwY2/1/)**

Comment: Ha ha ha! Love demo2!  Thanks for demo 1, that's what I needed.  It was the "inline-block" that was doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.button,.field{display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;padding:5px;border:1px solid #ccc;width:50%;}
.button{text-align:right;}
.field{text-align:left;color: #002c5a;}
div{display:table;margin:0 auto;width:100%;}
.field span{display:block;}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/jWTm3/)